# Cordova postMessage hit Refused to load gap-iab:// because it does not appear in the frame-src directive of the Content Security Policy

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I try to pass value from IOS inAppBrowser using `webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage()` and was hit with following error

> Refused to load gap-iab://message/ because it does not appear in the frame-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

- IOS version 12.4
- InAppBrowser version 3.1.0
- Cordova version 9
- Cordova platform version ios 5.1.1

would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: any solution for this?